# Personal Access Token isn't working although username and pat code are correct

Tags: git, github, git-push

My mate has created a public repository and pushed some files onto it correctly with no errors shown
When I modified some files, added them and committed changes to branch main, but when I tried to use `**git push origin main**` github asked me to login my account to complete the operation
I typed my username correctly and pasted my *Personal Access Token*(PAT) code but it all falls down
giving the error

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about- 
remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of 
authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Zainmansour/ytdlProject.git/'
```

if someone/anyone has already faced this issue,
please throw the type of help you know

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will. Thanks for notifying me, and about the problem it's been fixed